# How to create a blog post in my Web application? What database I should use for that?

Tags: java, javascript, blogs

I wish to create a blog post in my web application. How to make it? I am confused. I am using Java on the server side. But when I started working I was stuck. How to go forward? How should I work on it?

**EDIT:**

1. I am using using Java in server side, 2. JavaScript and [DWR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWR_%28Java%29) in client side, 3. the MySQL database and [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) as driver to connect to the database, 4. webserver- [Jetty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29) 6.

   I initially made a text Area and added a submit button. If we click the submit button the content gets saved in the MySQL database. The textarea size is varchar[250]. I have kept. Now for a blog page, what should I do next?
   I thought of having the blog post like this,

   when I click the blog link in my page

   - The dialog box should open wit a text area, so that the user can enter the contents and 
     save the blog using the submit button.
   - after the blog is saved the blog should appear on the page only as readable. Now there should appear a link "add comments" when user clicks that the user should be able to add the user's comments.
     This is what I thought of doing initially. But I don't know how to proceed further. Any suggestions. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways:

- EJB 3 to play with JPA entities using EntityManager in session beans
- Spring Framework with Hibernate/JPA
- Spring Framework with custom RowMappers (very primitive ORM)
- Ibatis
- JDBC - the most simple way and low-level way to access database

This is just a roadmap for you - you have to learn it by googling for some tutorials. You may start with JDBC or Spring using row mappers as they are the simplest ones.

Please make your question clearer.

Comment: ya I will use JDBC and mysql for DB. I know to use them. But i am strucked up openly saying in logic. How a blog works and how should i work on it step wise?Please guide

Comment: Oh I see. If it's that simple you should just follow some JDBC tutorial. You will get to know how a blog works by creating yours. There's no better way to learn than practising.